# How to install Barman with pg_receivewal and pg_basebackup without install PostgreSQL server?

Tags: postgresql, barman

Follow the official document, it's only necessary to install barman by yum or apt straightforward:

http://docs.pgbarman.org/release/2.10/#installation

Unnecessary to install PostgreSQL server on the barman server.

But in order to use barman, these 2 libraries are necessary: `pg_receivewal` and `pg_basebackup`. They are in the path `/usr/pgsql-10/bin/` if install PostgreSQL server.

How to make them out without install PostgreSQL server? Is there anyway?

Comment: Please describe your system.  With `apt` on Ubuntu 18.04 (and I assume others), installing barman automatically installs those two binaries as dependencies without installing the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the given URL also says in the System requirements section:

> ```
> Linux/Unix
> Python >= 3.4
> Python modules:
>     argcomplete
>     argh >= 0.21.2
>     psycopg2 >= 2.4.2
>     python-dateutil
>     setuptools
> PostgreSQL >= 8.3
> rsync >= 3.0.4 (optional for PostgreSQL >= 9.2)
> ```

It looks like you need to install PostgreSQL server.

Comment: Oh, you are right. It's the key point!

Answer (score 0):

I have made a test with PostgreSQL client 10 on CentOS 7:

```
# yum info postgresql10            
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.proxad.net
 * centos-sclo-rh: centos.mirror.fr.planethoster.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: centos.mirrors.proxad.net
 * extras: centos.mirrors.proxad.net
 * updates: centos.mirrors.proxad.net
Installed Packages
Name        : postgresql10
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 10.12
Release     : 1PGDG.rhel7
Size        : 8.3 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : pgdg10
Summary     : PostgreSQL client programs and libraries
URL         : https://www.postgresql.org/
License     : PostgreSQL
Description : PostgreSQL is an advanced Object-Relational database management system (DBMS).
            : The base postgresql package contains the client programs that you'll need to
            : access a PostgreSQL DBMS server, as well as HTML documentation for the whole
            : system.  These client programs can be located on the same machine as the
            : PostgreSQL server, or on a remote machine that accesses a PostgreSQL server
            : over a network connection.  The PostgreSQL server can be found in the
            : postgresql10-server sub-package.
            : 
            : If you want to manipulate a PostgreSQL database on a local or remote PostgreSQL
            : server, you need this package. You also need to install this package
            : if you're installing the postgresql10-server package.
```

It has following executables

```
# ls -rtl /usr/pgsql-10/bin
total 2372
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 581984 11 févr 23:04 psql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 126152 11 févr 23:04 pgbench
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  79576 11 févr 23:04 pg_waldump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 125752 11 févr 23:04 pg_upgrade
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  24784 11 févr 23:04 pg_test_timing
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  29104 11 févr 23:04 pg_test_fsync
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  79744 11 févr 23:04 pg_rewind
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 159544 11 févr 23:04 pg_restore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  67568 11 févr 23:04 pg_receivewal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  92616 11 févr 23:04 pg_dumpall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 384352 11 févr 23:04 pg_dump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  28752 11 févr 23:04 pg_config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105488 11 févr 23:04 pg_basebackup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  28816 11 févr 23:04 pg_archivecleanup
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  54488 11 févr 23:04 dropuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  54520 11 févr 23:04 dropdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  59272 11 févr 23:04 createuser
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  58840 11 févr 23:04 createdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63256 11 févr 23:04 vacuumdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  58960 11 févr 23:04 reindexdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  54448 11 févr 23:04 pg_isready
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  58872 11 févr 23:04 clusterdb
#
```

This means it should be possible to install only PostgreSQL client for barman.